# how to allow only arabic characters in form text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to allow only arabic characters in form text field    and  i tried with this code but its not working with keyup  its working for keypress but its not working with keyup it is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Character Filtering</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckEnglishOnly(field)
    {
        var sNewVal = "";
        var sFieldVal = field.value;

        for(var i = 0; i < sFieldVal.length; i++) {

            var ch = sFieldVal.charAt(i);

            var c = ch.charCodeAt(0);

            if(c < 0 || c > 255) {
                // Discard
            }
            else {
                sNewVal += ch;
            }
        }

        field.value = sNewVal;
    }

    function CheckArabicOnly(field)
    {     
        var sNewVal = "";
        var sFieldVal = field.value;

        for(var i = 0; i < sFieldVal.length; i++) {

            var ch = sFieldVal.charAt(i);
            var c = ch.charCodeAt(0);

            if(c < 1536 || c > 1791) {
                // Discard

            }
            else {
                sNewVal += ch;
               $( "#txtArabic" ).focus(); 
            }
        }

        field.value = sNewVal;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

Arabic Only (onchange): <input type="text" id="txtArabic" if(onkeyup) { onkeyup="CheckArabicOnly(this);" }  elseif(onpaste) { onkeyup="CheckArabicOnly(this);" }/><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Any one know would be highly appreciated

Comment: Use $( "#element" ).focus();

Comment: where should i use that that in my code

Comment: At the point after validation ie when you want to set the focus.

Comment: didn't get u can you edit my code by keeping your code

Comment: should i use jquery libery for that i dont know jquery

Comment: not working  i am keeping updated code check now

Comment: not working for that  can you check my video first so you can get my issue

Comment: What you mean by "not going to first or middle text after keyup". Is it like, the focus is not going to another text field?

Comment: Don't you need to set the [`dir="rtl"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) attribute on the input if you want to type arabic in it?

Comment: when i click on textfield i am trying to keep arabic works and english if the english words are there it will remove that but on that time when validating when i click in middle of text in input field  its not going to middle or first line in textfield its just going last line in that textfield